# Moving UIImageView with a loop stutters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have a code that creates a `UIImageView` at random intervals which then calls a method that will loop an animation to move them down the screen.

```
//This is called after an image is created
-(void)loopImage:(UIImageView *)image {
    [self moveImage:image];

    if (image.frame.origin.y > 300) {
        [image removeFromSuperview];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(loopImage:) withObject:image afterDelay:1.0f / 60.0f];
    }
}

-(void)moveImage:(UIImageView *)image {
    image.frame = CGRectMake(image.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y + 3, 20, 20);
}
```

This works completely fine as it does what I want it to do, but the movement of the image is not smooth. Occasionally, on its trip down the screen it will stutter and move back a few pixels (Not just on the simulator but on my test device, an iPhone 5s, as well). Is there any way I can smoothly move the image down the screen but still be able to check for collisions?

Comment: Why didnt the uiview  animateWithDuration work? It realy seems to be it's duty here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and proper way here is to use `[UIView animateWithDuration]`. What you use doesnt guarantee proper execution order in the view loop i think.